# Can you post images to your own profile using Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been looking around for a definite answer on this topic but I couldn't find any definitive word on it.

What I would like to do is let users log into their own FB profile and post pictures and videos.
Can I do that via the APIs nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The user permission "publish_actions" was deprecated on [August 1, 2018](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/). Publishing something on the user stream is no longer possible via the Graph API. You have to use the [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/) instead.